# Almost-trivial families of singular varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $V$ is a variety over $\mathbb{C}$ that is singular at $P$. I'm looking locally so let's actually take $V'$ to be $\mathrm{Spec}$ of the completion of the local ring of $V$ at $P$.

There may exist nontrivial deformations of $V'$ that leave it looking essentially the same. For example, let $V'=\mathrm{Spec}(k[[x,y]]/(x^3y-xy^3)).$ This is a planar quadruple point. If we slightly change the slopes of the four lines, we will get a non-isomorphic singularity. To see this, note that the projectivized tangent space is a $\mathbb{P}^1$ with four marked points, and an isomorphism must act by an isomorphism on this $\mathbb{P}^1,$ which would preserve the cross-ratio of the four points.

However, changing the slopes of the lines (provided they are still distinct) is unlikely to change any numerical invariants we care to name, and for example should not change the topological type of $V'$.

My questions:

1) How can we make rigorous the sense in which this family is "almost trivial"?

2) Given a singularity $V'$, can we tell whether it has " almost trivial " deformations like these? More specifically, maybe infinitesimal ones are classified by some group?

Comment: Try googling "equisingular deformation".

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I'm trying to understand Zariski's definition of equisingularity, though it only seems to be defined for hypersurfaces (presumably in affine space) with codimension 1 singular locus. Hartshorne mentions it in passing in Deformation Theory, but does not give a definition.